# clearing interval after counter reach 0 or reset

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to make simple game but I have problem to manage counter and to clear interval after counter reaches 0 or I click reset button. It works when It reaches 0, but when I try to implement it to reset button, counter is reseting but then goes with double speed.

```
let counter = 60;
let healthPoints = 3;
let points = 0;

document.querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', resetGame);


function countTime() {
    const timer = document.querySelector('.timer');
    const countTime = setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        timer.innerHTML = + counter;
        if (counter == 0) {
            alert('Game over')
            clearInterval(countTime);
        }
    }, 1000)
}

function resetGame() {
    newBoard();
    counter = 60;
    healthPoints = 4;
    points = 0;
    clearInterval(countTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countTime argument your are passing to the clearInterval function inside the resetGame function is a reference to the function called countTime. You need to rename the variable and declare it globally:

```
let counter = 60;
let healthPoints = 3;
let points = 0;
let t = null;
document.querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', resetGame);
function countTime() {
    const timer = document.querySelector('.timer');
    t = setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    timer.innerHTML = + counter; 
    if (counter == 0) {
      alert('Game over')     
      clearInterval(t);
    }
   }, 1000)
 }

function resetGame() {
  newBoard();
  counter = 60;
  healthPoints = 4;
  points = 0;
  clearInterval(t);
}
```

Comment: thank you all guys, this solution fitted the most to my problem:) But thank you all, yeah I saw a problem that interval might to not be cleared when I click button but didn't know how to solve it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` returns a value that you pass to `clearInterval()` when you want to stop the timer. You need to save this in a scope where `resetGame()` can see it. You are declaring inside `countTime()` which means it's only in scope there.

Here I've named it `interval` and defined it outside both functions so both functions have access to it:

```js
let counter = 60;
let healthPoints = 3;
let points = 0;
let interval;

document.querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', resetGame);


function countTime() {
    const timer = document.querySelector('.timer');
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        timer.innerHTML = + counter;
        if (counter == 0) {
            alert('Game over')
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000)
}

function resetGame() {
    counter = 60;
    healthPoints = 4;
    points = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
    countTime()
}

countTime()
```

```html
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
<div class = "timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you didn't actually cleared the interval, you must provide to the clearInterval function which needs an **interval id** in order to know which interval to clear. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

This id is actually returned when you call the setInterval function, so your countTime variable is your interval ID.

This is why when it reaches zero it works it is because you are properly clearing the interval by provided its id to the clearInterval function and on the contrary you are just providing the function reference to the clearInterval function in your resetGame function

So what you can do is actually returning your intervalId from your countTime and provided this to your resetGame function :

```
function countTime() {
    ...
    const timer = document.querySelector('.timer');
    // I renamed it just to be clear
    const countTimeIntervalID = setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    timer.innerHTML = + counter;
    if (counter == 0) {
        alert('Game over')
        clearInterval(countTime);
    }
 }, 1000)
   return countTimeIntervalID
}
let countTimeIntervalID = countTime();
function resetGame() {
     ...
    clearInterval(countTimeIntervalID);
}
```

Also, note that the reason why when you clicked the reset button it doubled the counter time it is because since you didn't clear the first one, it was still running so there were actually to intervals running and updating the same .timer dom element